# Manually Passing a Foreign key Value

Tags: laravel

I can not pass a foreign key value (which is user_id) to my newly created article.

**Here is my code...**

```
<?php

if (is_null($request->user_id)) {
    $request->user_id = $user->user_id;
}

$request->validate(['title' => 'Required|string|min:3', 'body' => 'Required|string|min:5', 'user_id' => 'Required|exists:users,user_id']);

if ($article = Article::create($request->all())) {
    event(new ArticleCreated($user));
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'reason' => 'Article Created successfully', $article]);
} else {
    return 'Article could not be created';
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: paste the full code and what is the error you are getting

Comment: whats in dd($request->all());?

Comment: I don't know if Laravel is case sensitive for validation functions, so the three `Required`s might not work. Aside from that: please note you have an exclamation mark `!` in your `user_id` validation instead of a pipe `|`.

Comment: Laravel is case sensitive it should be required not Required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
 if($article = Article::create($request->all())) {
    $article->user_id = $request->user_id; 
    $article->save();

    event(new ArticleCreated($user));
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'reason' => 'Article Created successfully', $article]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


  $request->validate([
    'title' => 'Required|string|min:3', 
    'body' => 'Required|string|min:5', 
  ]);

  $data = $request->all();

  //you don't need to validate user_id is correct 
  //if you are using auth middleware in the route
  $user = auth()->user()
  $data['user_id] = $user->id

  if ($article = Article::create($data)) {
     event(new ArticleCreated($user));
     return response()->json([
          'success' => true, 
          'reason' => 'Article Created successfully', 
          $article
     ]);
  } else {
      return 'Article could not be created';
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I liked your way but still i can not pass user_id to the newly created article. user_id is null in the newly created article.

Comment: post your `$fillable` of the `Article` model

Answer (score 0):

Check your fillable array in Article model, there must be user_id, and check if the user id is passed in the `$request->all()`.